# Jade not able to link to javascript file + node.js

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm running a webserver that renders jade files.  In the jade files I have some javascript files.  The page renders fine but the javascript files are not being found.

**Node server**

```
var http = require('http')
  , url = require('url')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , jade = require('jade')
  , server;

server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

  switch (path) {

    case '/audio':
        var options = {pretty: true};
        jade.renderFile('myJadeFile.jade', options, function(err, html) {
          if (err) return send404(res);
          res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
          res.write(html, 'utf8');
          res.end();
        });
        break;

    default: send404(res);
  }
});

function send404(res) {
  res.writeHead(404);
  res.write('404');
  res.end();
}

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("listening on port:3000");
});
```

**Jade File**

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    title Please Work
    script(src="myJSFile.js")
  body
    #container
      h1 It worked!
```

I get this error:
`GET http://localhost:3000/myJSFile.js 404 (Not Found)`

It's not finding the file and I'm not sure what I have to put on the serverside jade options to find the javascript file.  All files are in the same folder.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you seen: http://expressjs.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jade is an HTML rendering tool, so it is rendering a standard `<script>` tag. It does not compile the JS into the HTML file itself. You will need to provide handlers in your `case` to handle any dependent files so that the browser can fetch them.

Here's an example for this specific case, assuming that you have myJSFile.js in the same directory as your server file.

```
case '/myJSFile.js':
  fs.createReadStream(__dirname + path).pipe(res);
  break;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was using `fs.readFile()` to handle the dependent files but I like `fs.createReadStream()` better!